# Freezing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to freeze columns in this manner in Google Sheets:

Freeze A-C, then
As you scroll past F, freeze it, then
As you scroll past I, freeze it too?

To help understand why I need this, columns D & E calculate F, and G & H calculate I, so when I am looking at the data to make my decision, I only need to see A-C, F & I.

Can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only freeze the first *n* rows or columns. But you can create a macro that would freeze the initial columns and hide those that you don't need (and another to un-hide those columns back).